# How can $F$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ if $f$ is unbounded when $x>b$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Define $F$ on $[a,b]$ as the integral of $f$ from $a$ to $x$. 
According to Spivak (289), if $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$, then $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Conceptually, how can $F$ be continuous at $b$? Consider an $f$ such that it is unbounded at $x>b$. Then, it does not seem that $F(b + d)$ is arbitrarily close to $F(b)$, as the values of $f$ are unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

Since the domain of $F$ is $[a,b]$, asserting that $F$ is continuous at $b$ means that $\lim_{t\to b^-}F(t)=F(b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous on $[a,b]$ only requires that
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0} f(b-\varepsilon)=f(b).
$$